# Is there an example of a convex combination that is not conic?

Tags: convex-hulls, convex-cone

I am curious to know if all convex combinations are conic combinations?
A convex combination is: $$C=\{x|x=\alpha_1x_1+...+\alpha_kx_k, \alpha_1+...+\alpha_k=1,\alpha_i\geq0\}$$
A conic combination is:$$C=\{x|x=\alpha_1x_1+...+\alpha_kx_k, \alpha_i\geq0\}$$

Answer (score 1):

There's hardly anything to be curious about when convex combination litterally has an additional condition compared to conic combination.